# How could I add product price on auto complete of prestashop quick search?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, autocomplete, prestashop, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Bellow you can see an example of html generated code of my auto complete on quick search module. Is any controller or view on Prestashop that this html code is generated dynamically? I simply want to add a third element (except from product thumb and product title) on each li which is product price..

```html
<div class="ac_results" style="position: absolute; width: 325px; top: 99.5286px; left: 885.814px;">
  <ul>
    <li class="ac_even ac_over">
      <img src="my-img-src" alt="my-img-alt">
      <span class="ac_product_name">My Product Title</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is generated in JS/jQuery plugin: `/js/jquery/plugins/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js`.

By default there is no price data. You should modify PHP of the module you are using for the search. Or just look for another search module.